# Compare content of two folders/disks (including timestamps,permissions)

Tags: files, permissions, terminal, timestamps, diff

I have two directories on two different hard drives and want to check if the content is really **exactly** the same.
From what I read I can use `diff -rq dir1 dir2` to check if files are missing or differ.

> `-q`,`--brief` 
> report only when files differ  
>  
> `-r`,`--recursive` 
> recursively compare any subdirectories found

However as far as I see diff does not check if the permissions or timestamps differ.
Is there another parameter for diff or other tool where it is possible to check that as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mtree(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mtree) is an excellent tool for this:

The command:

```
$ mtree -cp path/on/hostA -K sha256 | ssh hostB mtree -p path/on/hostB
```

will report differences between the heirarchy in `hostA:path/on/hostA` and the heirarchy in `hostB:path/on/hostB` in terms of type, size, timestamp, permissions, and content.  Additionally, missing entries (not found on `hostB`) or extraneous entries (found only on `hostB`) are reported.

If the heirarcies are identical, `mtree` will issue no output and return an exit code of 0:

```
$ mtree -cp path/on/hostA -K sha256 | ssh hostB mtree -p path/on/hostB && echo match
match
```

Otherwise, `mtree` will return a non-zero exit code, and itemize the entries that differ:

```
# create some differences on hostB:

$ ssh hostB 'rmdir path/on/hostB/d'
$ ssh hostB 'mkdir path/on/hostB/e'
$ ssh hostB 'date > path/on/hostB/b/B'
$ ssh hostB 'touch path/on/hostB/b/BB'
$ ssh hostB 'chmod 644 path/on/hostB/c/C'

# and then compare:

$ mtree -cp path/on/hostA -K sha256 | ssh hostB mtree -p path/on/hostB || echo fail
.:      modification time (Tue May 18 13:27:20 2021, Tue May 18 13:45:06 2021)
extra: e
b/BB:   modification time (Tue May 18 13:27:28 2021, Tue May 18 13:50:01 2021)
b/B:    modification time (Tue May 18 13:27:03 2021, Tue May 18 13:46:04 2021)
        sha256 (0x4f7986b5a925296c575043e73e76b59b6eb84da37c50f2e86baaafc75e2fcdca, 0x46f3f4e748cfef2a4cd679d6c9723cb44eb0526b760854fcef33bb97ca27fae2)
c/C:    permissions (0600, 0644)
missing: ./d
fail
```

Line by line, `mtree` tells you that:

- the path root directories themselves (`.`) have different timestamps
- there is an extra entry `e` on `hostB` that does not appear on `hostA`
- the modification time of entry `b/BB` differs between the two hosts (but the content does not)
- the modification time AND the content (`SHA256` hash) of entry `b/B` differ between the two hosts
- the permissions of entry `c/C` differ between the two hosts
- `hostB` is missing the entry `./d`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `diff` alone can't do that, but if you are using shell which supports process substitution (like bash/zsh) you can incorporate `state` command into diff like this

```
#working example:

echo "some file" > foo
cp foo bar
diff <(stat foo) <(stat bar)

chmod o+x bar
diff <(stat foo) <(stat bar)
```

**NOTE** that process substitution is not POSIX compliant so if you need something with more portability you will need to script it yourself. Above `diff` command can be roughly translated to POSIX like this:

```
mkfifo /var/tmp/fifo1
mkfifo /var/tmp/fifo2
stat foo >/var/tmp/fifo1 &
     stat bar >/var/tmp/fifo2 &
     diff /var/tmp/fifo1 /var/tmp/fifo2
rm /var/tmp/fifo1 /var/tmp/fifo2
```